# How to read data from android app with iOS app in local network

Tags: android, ios

here is architecture description:

- wifi router to create local network for other 2 devices:
- galaxy tab with android main app. It performs
  calculations. Calculation results update every 10 seconds.
- ipad 3. It needs to read calculations from android. Values on android app and
  iOS app must be synchronized (1-2 seconds delay to show results on
  ipad after android calculation updated)

How this solution can be achieved? Is it possible to run HTTP-server on android to provide REST API for iPAD? Maybe some other variants?

Thanks.

Comment: For this purpose a plain ``ServerSocket`` could be sufficient. But as for servers there exists I-Jetty at least; http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/

Comment: thanks! Our main priority - speed of developement. Looks like server can be developed faster. Is there some perfomance issues?

Comment: I would just establish socket to socket tcp connection.  Once the Android device has the updated data, it just needs to send to the other connected iOS device.  Not sure what library is available under Android, but under iOS you can use this https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket